# Android tutorial error: edit_message cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, android-activity

I tried to follow the android tutorial but after I try to run the code this error appears.
Here is my MainActivity.

```
    package com.example.menuexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.example.menuexample.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){ 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
        EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);  --HERE
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }


}
```

I have got in the activity_main :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" >

</EditText>
```

Also , strings.xml has:

```
<string name="edit_message">Test</string>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

to

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

because you have declared Edittext with editText1 id in xml layout but you are trying to find control id which is not exist